# Mac: HockeyApp SDK 3.1 programmatically add attachments to Feedback Messages?

Tags: objective-c, macos, hockeyapp

I'm noticing that the only platform HockeyApp doesn't intuitively allow attachments for Feedback right now is Mac. Does anyone have insight as to how I can append a simple string to a feedback message or even an NSData blob?

Looking through the documentation I see two protocols that can be implemented.

1) [BITHockeyManagerDelegate](http://hockeyapp.net/help/sdk/mac/3.1.0/Protocols/BITHockeyManagerDelegate.html)

2) [BITCrashManagerDelegate](http://hockeyapp.net/help/sdk/mac/3.1.0/Protocols/BITCrashManagerDelegate.html)

Whats puzzling me is that neither of these have a reference to the FeedbackManager. The only thing that's somewhat relevant is the CrashManagerDelegate's mention of
 `- (BITHockeyAttachment *)attachmentForCrashManager:(BITCrashManager *)crashManager` Though, this seems to only be called when sending a crash report. Perhaps I'm wrong?

The HockeyApp [git repo](https://github.com/bitstadium/HockeySDK-Mac) seems to have a class, [BITFeedbackManagerPrivate.h](https://github.com/bitstadium/HockeySDK-Mac/blob/develop/Classes/Feedback/BITFeedbackManagerPrivate.h), containing the functionality I'm looking for, but is inaccessible from HockeyApp's pre-built .dylib.

After building from source, seemingly no other class exposes it's methods, so I'm trying to figure out if this feature has been implemented yet or if I'm missing something.

Any insight is greatly appreciated. Cheers,

Zack

Comment: This rather seems to be either a support ticket for HockeyApp or a ticket to the GitHub repository, but nothing of the scope of SO. Please file one of those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The repository doesn't have a feature for that at the moment, not even the Private headers. The features are available on the iOS SDK and will soon be brought over to the Mac SDK. So far the demand for things like this had been very low so the priority wasn't that high.

Please file a ticket with support or the GitHub repository for such requests, so we can quickly answer and react and don't have to search StackOverflow :)

Thanks!

Comment: Cheers! I appreciate the response. Just wanted to double check that I wasn't missing anything or maybe there was existing code that I was missing. Enjoy your weekend.